# Android select multiple records

Tags: android, sqlite, select, rows

with this query I select a record, now I want to select the record with the next ID, so I should combine these two SELECT, how can I do?

```
String sql ="SELECT _id, date, score, score1 FROM Points 
WHERE score = '"+score_ricevuto+"' ORDER BY date DESC";

String sql ="SELECT _id, score, score2 FROM
 Points WHERE score = '"+score_ricevuto+"';
```

Answer (score 0):

Like so:

```
SELECT _id, date, score, score1, score2 
  FROM Points 
 WHERE score = '"+score_ricevuto+"' 
 ORDER BY date DESC";
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a better way for selecting multiple records.

```
SELECT _id, date, score, score1 FROM Points  WHERE score = '"+score_ricevuto+"' and _id IN (" + id + "," + (id+1) + " ORDER BY date DESC";
```